# TFS 2010 build email notification when build is running beyond permissible time span

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am using TFS 2010 for build service. I need to send an email if the build is running for longer time.

For ex: Suppose the build normally runs for 10 mins, but now if the build is running for more than 20 mins... i need to send an email notification.

May I have your help on this?

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is not available out of the box. This can however, make a great feature request, raise it for consideration here => http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio

However, to get this to work here is what you can do... Write a tfs build activity which using the tfs api extracts the last build execution time and insert that at various places in the process workflow ideally before and after each work flow task to check how much time has the build already consumed while measuring this against the expected time. Use the email notification task to send out an email accordingly.

Here is an example that shows u how to get the last build details, http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/01/11/tfs-api-part-33-get-build-definitions-and-build-details.aspx and here a custom task example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, query the TFS Build Queue and check the runtime of the builds in progress. When any of the builds exceeds the defined thresholds, send the email. This can be done in a windows service with relative ease.

You'd use the TFS Client Object Model to query the builds like this. Tarun already provided a nice link to that.

Comment: Once you've written the appropriate code in the client object model, you can write a custom build activity to fail the build after a period of time. Add that to your build process template and you're just about done.